# Unrelated tables in ERD

Tags: database-design, erd

Simple question - do you include unrelated tables in an ERD. By unrelated I mean a table that is not associated with any other table in the database.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot include unrelated entities in ER Diagram.An entity should atleast participate in one relationship to exist in ERD.

Answer (score 3):

Yes of course - assuming the purpose of the diagram is to convey something about those entity types (attribute names, keys, other constraints etc). Since you have asked the question I guess that they are in fact "associated" in some significant way but they just don't happen to involve any of the rather limited types of relationship that are usually shown as lines on an ER diagram. Nothing wrong with putting them in a diagram if you find it useful to do so.